# How to match everything between strings including multiple lines?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing my own template engine and I'm working on the loop part, I thought I should use regex to help me match whatever loops there are in the template

I came up with the following

```
{foreach \$list as \$item}(.+?)${\/endforeach}\s
```

I need it to match everything between those two strings and those two strings as well, so if my text was

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
{foreach $list as $item}
    <td>{$item}</td>
{/endforeach}
   </body>
</html>
```

I need it to match

```
{foreach $list as $item}
    <td>{$item}</td>
{/endforeach}
```

However the regex that I wrote is matching it until a new line happens then it stops matching even though I use \s

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: `/{foreach \$list as \$item}(.+?){\/endforeach}/s`. Check it out https://regex101.com/r/hB6zC0/1

Comment: @HamZa Thanks a lot. However, can you explain to me what I've been doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify delimiters: it can be `/`, `#`, `~` and much more. It will look like `/regex/`. Then you need to add the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.` (dot): `/regex/s`. You wrote `\s` which means "match a white space". I also removed `$` after `(.+?)` since it means end of string.